# How to define Open Api 3.0 documentation for requestBody of content " text / csv (UTF-8)"

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-3.0

I am new to swagger.
I have an endpoint which is accepting input in the format of 'text / csv (UTF-8).
I want to add open api documentation for the end point.
But I am not finding any examples from the official website
[request body description swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/)

```
CSV string = "header1;header2|loream,2"

ContentType = `text/csv(UTF-8)`
```

I have to specify

```
header1: 
   type: string
header2:
   type: integer
```

Any suggestions will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: For requestBody 'application / json' we can define the properties of each key. But when it is text / csv, there is no documentation available on the official site. So how can I proceed?
There is documentation available for file upload input related to it. But in my case it is text input.

Comment: have you advanced on this? can you share anything you found out?